# Elasticsearch re-index data count is different

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one elasticsearch index and I want to a re-index old data to new index. data_a -> data_b

I am using **elasticdump** to copy data from one index to another index. The problem is that after copying everything successfully, data count is not matching. I tried re-indexing using other tools but getting the same issue.

Re-index details are giving below.

**data_a**

```
size: 130Mi (259Mi)
docs: 62,238 (71,224)
```

---

**data_b**

```
size: 91.7Mi (183Mi)
docs: 51,312 (51,312)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: What is your indexes information num of shards etc. And How can you get this numbers? From head plugin?

Comment: Also, can you show the elasticdump commands you're running?

Comment: elasticdump --input=http://myserver.com/data_a/data --output=http://myserver.com/data_b/data --type=data

Comment: @hkulekci -- Number of Shards : 5 and Number of Replicas : 1 (Yes I am getting these values using head tool) I checked using _count api also and figures are same as above.

Comment: Some times ES can not handle very fast bulk insert operations if your cluster is not as good as necessary. Can you check your elasticsearch.log file while you are running your dump script? If you have any error in there, please share with us.

Comment: @hkulekci there is no error in elasticsearch.log, everything is showing successful.